# Read .dat Files from HDFS in Spark Scala to apply SQL Functions

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a folder of .dat files in my HDFS cluster. 
I want to apply sql functions on the files in that particular folder.
They are of the format :

```
    /user/hu/file.dat
    /user/hu/file2.dat
    etc etc
```

I am using the following functions to do it :

```
   val datanew = sc.textFile("user/hu");
   val tables = ssqlc.read.json(datanew);
   tables.registerTempTable("tabledata");
```

I later want to perform the function :

```
tweets = shsqlc.sql("SELECT  id as Id, " +"number as UserId," +"body as newbody")
```

But as i run this program I get an error that table doesnt exist. 
Can someone please help ?

Comment: Have you created Scheme for your data? What I am doing is a bit different, instead of creating a table I create a DataFrame (in Java) with StructType.

Comment: Your sql is invalid - it does not even include the `tabledata` table name in it. Please provide more complete information.